# How to create to step commands and how to send privet messages using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot that when you wright "/encryptkey message" it will translate it to Mors code I'm trying to make it so when someone wrights "/decryptkey" it will send them a private msg with the decrypted code (iv already have a valuable called last_crypt it is the decrypted last message)
problems:
1- doesn't send direct messages
2. thinks the /decryptkey needs to be on the same message
here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

MORSE_CODE_DICT = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-',
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-',
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}

def encrypt(message):
    cipher = ''
    for letter in message:
        if letter != ' ':
  
            cipher += MORSE_CODE_DICT[letter] + ' '
        else:
            cipher += ' '
  
    return cipher
  
def decrypt(message):
  
    message += ' '
  
    decipher = ''
    citext = ''
    for letter in message:
  
        if (letter != ' '):
  
            i = 0
  
            citext += letter
  
        else:
            i += 1
  
            if i == 2 :
  
                decipher += ' '
            else:
  
                decipher += list(MORSE_CODE_DICT.keys())[list(MORSE_CODE_DICT
                .values()).index(citext)]
                citext = ''
  
    return decipher


class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message): 
        word_list = ['/encryptkey']
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        message_Content = message.content

        if len(message_Content) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in message_Content:

                    query = message_Content
                    stopwords = ['/encryptkey']
                    querywords = query.split()

                    resultwords  = [word for word in querywords if word.lower() not in stopwords]
                    result11 = ' '.join(resultwords)

                    result = encrypt(result11.upper())
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send(result)

                    last_crypt = decrypt(result.upper())
                    print(result)
                    print(last_crypt)

                    async def on_message(self, message):
                        if message.author == self.user:
                            return
                        
                        message_Content = message.content

                        if len(message_Content) > 0:
                            if message_Content == "/decryptkey":
                                await client.send_message(message.author, last_crypt)

client = MyClient()
client.run('#token_here')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `discord.Member.send` to send a DM to the user. In this case, instead of `message.channel.send`, you would want `message.author.send`.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback but it doesn't work it says "Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"

Comment: You need `await` before it.

Comment: Thanks it worked but because you didn't answer the entire question i will not mark it as solved thanks.

Comment: after someone wrights "/encryptkey message" i at it that if someone wrights "/decryptkey" it will send them a private dm with the decrypted text

Comment: do you mean subcommands?
for that you will need the commands extension so it is easier

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: for that you will need to change it to use the commands extension... you've everything in an `on_message` event rn. The commands extension lets you make actual commands
let me show you an example [here](https://github.com/dank-tagg/bot-template/blob/27fd16d3f38348c0822ebf6e9231e5d108f631ce/main.py#L25)